# ST_intersects geography

Tags: postgis

I am trying to figure out something, I am using postgis 2.3 on postgres 9.6

**ST_intersects** on **Geography** returns false although two geographies are intersecting.
In order to debug I tried the same query using **Geometry** and the two intersected.

Can someone help me to explain that?

Example:

I am running this query:

```
select ST_intersects(ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890))'), ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47))'))  from table limit 1;
```

I get:

```
 st_intersects 
---------------
 f
(1 row)
```

and when I run:

```
 select ST_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890))'), ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47))')) from  table limit 1;
```

I get:

```
 st_intersects
 ---------------
  t
 (1 row)
```

Comment: 1. Check your question - difference between this two queries  is only ';' at the end.
2. There is no geography in both of them...

Comment: thank, I updated the first query, the diffrence is the use of ST_GeogFromText or ST_GeomFromText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ST_Intersects -- returns True if Geometries/Geography spatially intersect in 2D`. Your queries should return same result if you convert from `POLYGON` (in your case with 5 vertices) to `LINESTRING`. Test:

```
SELECT 
 ST_Intersects(
 ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890)'), 
 ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47)'));


SELECT 
 ST_Intersects(
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326; LINESTRING(12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890)'), 
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326; LINESTRING(-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47)'));
```

Update::

Actually, using `Polygon` is just fine for `ST_Intersects`. I realize that `Linestring` isn't what you want -- returns false because one is completely inside the other. The issue is that these two polygons are far apart in spherical coordinate system. Check:

```
SELECT 
 ST_Distance(
 ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890))'), 
 ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47))'));
```

==> 0

```
SELECT 
 ST_Distance(
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890))'), 
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47))'));
```

==> 6743507.32

You can of course cast `geography` to `geometry` type as follows to get the desired output:

```
SELECT 
 ST_Intersects(
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((12.856 41.890,12.856 41.935,12.811 41.935,12.811 41.890,12.856 41.890))')::geometry, 
 ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-170 -47,174 -47,174 77,-170 77,-170 -47))')::geometry);
```

Comment: thanks, I don't understand your answer, does it mean that `POLYGON` is not 2d?

Comment: alslo, both queries return false

Comment: @GuyDoulberg My bad. `POLYGON` is indeed 2D as each virtex has 2 coordinates -- I confused vertices with dimension. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna, what are the implications of such casting? am I loosing something?

Comment: @GuyDoulberg short answer is that it does not matter much, esp. for small polygons. Long answer at http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html section 18.3 and 18.4.